# What is the simple way to check if there are only two elements in a pair of Scheme list?

Tags: list, scheme

I have '((5 1 0)), and want my condition to be false as it contains more than 2 elements. 'Pair?' function gives #t if used. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pair?` procedure is useful for testing if an object is a cons-cell (and all non-empty lists are cons-cells). Use it together with `length`:

```
(define p1 '(5 1 0))
(and (pair? p1) (= (length p1) 2))
=> #f

(define p2 '(5 1))
(and (pair? p2) (= (length p2) 2))
=> #t
```

I took the liberty of changing the example, the one in the question `'((5 1 0))` is a *list* with a single element, which happens to be another list.

Comment: Thanks. can you please see my edit above? any help.. many thanks.

Comment: If you need further help, post a different question. Please don't edit the original question changing its scope.

Comment: I have posted it as a new question. Thanks. :)